# How to continously monitor and rename a file in numerical order that is being copied to the destination folder with same name

Tags: bash, shell

A server does export cache file(input.cache) every 3 hours. I am trying to continuously monitor the destination folder and rename the file in numerical order as they arrive. Something like

```
File=input.cache; if [ -e "$File" ]; then mv input.cache input-1.cache; fi
```

But, this should be running continuously and keep renaming them in numerical sequence as they arrive*(input-2.cache,input-3.cache ...input-n.cache)*. Any ideas on how to achieve this task is appreciated.

Comment: If you are using GNU coreutils, then just use `mv --backup=numbered input.cache input.cache.bak`. Thus `mv` automatically will make numbered backups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ethernal loop can be done with this:

```
while true; do
    your_code
done
```

But your HDD won't be happy with this code)
So it's better to run this check via `cron`
Add this line to `/etc/crontab`:

```
0 */3   * * *   your_user   i=1; [[ -e $File ]] && { while ls input-$i.cache 2> /dev/null; do ((i++)); done; mv $File input-$i.cache; }
```